# In the view of (some reason)

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can we use this expression in informal discussion as "because of"? For example

> I was late **in the view of** helping my mother to do laundry.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean "because of", although it's a good question and @StoneyB's answer helps explain why.  When we say "doing X *in view of* Y", it means something more like "considering Y" or "taking Y into account."  The idiom is always **in view of**; "in **the** view of" uses the word *view* literally, meaning "an opinion or way of thinking about something" or "the things that can be seen from a particular place".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither *in view of* nor *in the view of* means *because of*, although *in view of* comes close.

- *in **the** view of X* is completely unrelated. *View* here means "perspective, opinion", so the phrase means "according to X's perspective". The *of X* is more often expressed with a genitive.

  > In Trump's view, all undocumented foreigners should be deported forthwith.
- *in view of X* doesn't designate X as the cause of just any sort of event but specifically as a factor taken into consideration in a decision or judgment: the speaker has X "in view", figuratively visible, when making the decision.

  > We're shutting the event down early in view of the expected severe weather.

  So you can't say **I was in late in view of helping my mother do laundry*; but you might say *In view of her illness I decided to help my mother with her laundry, and that's why I was late*.

Comment: @Rathony - Ah, I was unaware of that.  That seems like a convention likely to conflict with the use of \* to begin italics.

Comment: There is a meta post about formatting on meta - http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/237/ I don't think it's authoritative, but it's a good starting point in my opinion, especially as a jumping off point for related discussions. @stangdon

Comment: @stangdon You can just escape the visible asterisk: `\*`. Or you can use a different asterisk character, such as ∗ (&lowast;).

Comment: @StoneyB I just noticed that _owing to_ has pretty much the same meaining. Can we replace _in view of_ with it in your example?